# Keymap from previous version aren't working in the version 3.5

Tags: customization, keymap

I was using version 2.91 and today I decided to move to the last version but I faced a problem, when I import the keymap from the previous version it simply doesn't work. I opened the keymap file from both versions and from the last version seems a little different from the elder one.
Due to a problem with my hand, I must use a tablet to work with Blender, so my keymaps are very customized, and making it by hand again would be a nightmare. Anyone could I help with it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I was using 2.93, then switch to version 4. Simply copy-paste content from folder `2.93` to  `4.0` method didn't work for me. I find solution which not perfect but it fix most problems with keybinds.

1. Open your old version of Blender then go to *Edit> Preferences > Keymap*
   then choose *Export* and save file
2. Open your new version, navigate to *Keymap* (same as previous step) and import your saved keymap file.
3. Dont forget to save Preferences if it not saving automatically

It didn't fix all problems, because UI and some functions has been changed, for those you have to reconfigure it by hand unfortunately.